# Column grand totals, tSQL Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot, common-table-expression

I currently have this script in development at the moment for a pivot which gives me Percentages of Maturity band by S&P Rating.  I have row grand totals as follows:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT  PortfolioID
        , MaturityBand
        , SandPRating
        , MaturitySort
        , (count(*)over(partition by PortfolioID,SandPRating,MaturityBand)*100.0)   --/Test2)*100 As Pct
        /
        (
            Select COUNT(*)
            From     @Worktable B
            Where B.PortfolioID = A.PortfolioID
        ) As Pct


FROM    @Worktable AS A
--WHERE SandPRating IS NOT NULL

UNION All

SELECT   PortfolioID
        , MaturityBand
        , 'SandPRating_Total' AS SandPRating
        , MaturitySort
        , COUNT(*) * 100.0
        /
        (
            Select COUNT(*)
            From     @Worktable AS B
            Where B.PortfolioID = A.PortfolioID
        ) AS Total_Pct
FROM    @Worktable AS A
--WHERE SandPRating IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY  PortfolioID, MaturityBand, MaturitySort
)
, CTE2
AS
(
SELECT  MaturityBand
        , SandPRating
        , MaturitySort
        , PCT
FROM    CTE
GROUP BY MaturityBand, SandPRating, MaturitySort, PCT 
)

SELECT   MaturityBand, [AAA],[AA+],[AA],[AA-],[A+],[A],[A-]
    ,[BBB+],[BBB],[BBB-],[BB+],[BB],[BB-],[B+],[B],[B-]
    ,[CCC+],[CCC],[CCC-],[CC],[C],[DDD],[DD],[D],[N.R.]
    ,[N.A.],[WR], [Unass], [SandPRating_Total]   
FROM    Cte2

PIVOT   

(MAX(PCT)
FOR SandPRating
IN      
(
[AAA],[AA+],[AA],[AA-],[A+],[A],[A-]
,[BBB+],[BBB],[BBB-],[BB+],[BB],[BB-],[B+],[B],[B-]
,[CCC+],[CCC],[CCC-],[CC],[C],[DDD],[DD],[D],[N.R.]
,[N.A.],[WR], [Unass], [SandPRating_Total])
) myPiv

ORDER BY MaturitySort
```

My pivot currently looks like this:

```
Maturity Band     AAA     AA     A    A-    BBB+     BBB-    BB+    BB   Total
Less Than 1 yr    2.63%   5%                2%                           9.63%
1 to 5 yrs                       5%         5%                           10%
5 to 10 yrs       5.00%                              5%                  10%
10 to 20 yrs                          2%                                 2%
More than 20 yrs  10%                                         6%    1%   17%
```

What i would like to have is this:

```
Maturity Band     AAA     AA     A    A-    BBB+     BBB-    BB+    BB   Total
Less Than 1 yr    2.63%   5%                2%                           9.63%
1 to 5 yrs                       5%         5%                           10%
5 to 10 yrs       5.00%                              5%                  10%
10 to 20 yrs                          2%                                 2%
More than 20 yrs  10%                                         6%    1%   17%
Total             17.63   5%     5%   2%    7%       5%       6%    1%   48.63%
```

However i would like to add column grand totals, can anyone help?

Comment: Can you give an example or the result what you are looking for?

Comment: i have edited above to provide an example.  This is just test data, the total of the total column should sum to 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maanged to answer this myself.  RecNo is just:

```
count(*) over (Partition by PortfolioID)
```

my script is now:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT  PortfolioID
        , MaturityBand
        , SandPRating
        , MaturitySort
        , SUM((1/RecNo)*100) AS Pct

FROM    @Worktable AS A
--WHERE SandPRating IS NOT NULL
Group by MaturitySort, MaturityBand, SandPRating, PortfolioID

UNION All

SELECT   PortfolioID
        , MaturityBand
        , 'SandPRating_Total' AS SandPRating
        , MaturitySort
        , COUNT(*) * 100.0
        /
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM     @Worktable AS B
            WHERE B.PortfolioID = A.PortfolioID
        ) AS Total_Pct
FROM    @Worktable AS A
--WHERE SandPRating IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY  MaturitySort, MaturityBand, PortfolioID
)
, CTE2
AS
(
SELECT  Grouping_ID(SandPRating, MaturityBand, MaturitySort) AS ID

     , CASE 
        WHEN Grouping_ID(SandPRating, MaturityBand, MaturitySort) = 3 THEN 'Total' 
        ELSE MaturityBand 
       END                                              AS MaturityBand

     , SandPRating

     , CASE 
        WHEN Grouping_ID(SandPRating, MaturityBand, MaturitySort) = 3 THEN 1000 
        ELSE MaturitySort 
       END                                              AS MaturitySort

     , SUM(Pct) AS PCT

FROM    CTE
GROUP BY ROLLUP (SandPRating
     , MaturityBand
     , MaturitySort)
)
--PIVOT
SELECT  MaturityBand, [AAA],[AA+],[AA],[AA-],[A+],[A],[A-]
    ,[BBB+],[BBB],[BBB-],[BB+],[BB],[BB-],[B+],[B],[B-]
    ,[CCC+],[CCC],[CCC-],[CC],[C],[DDD],[DD],[D],[N.R.]
    ,[N.A.],[WR],[Unass],[SandPRating_Total]     
FROM    (   SELECT SandPRating, MaturityBand, MaturitySort, PCT 
        FROM Cte2
        WHERE   ID = 0 or ID = 3
    ) AS x

PIVOT   (SUM(PCT)
        FOR SandPRating
        IN  ([AAA],[AA+],[AA],[AA-],[A+],[A],[A-]
            ,[BBB+],[BBB],[BBB-],[BB+],[BB],[BB-],[B+],[B],[B-]
            ,[CCC+],[CCC],[CCC-],[CC],[C],[DDD],[DD],[D],[N.R.]
            ,[N.A.],[WR],[Unass],[SandPRating_Total])
    ) myPiv
ORDER BY MaturitySort
```